# downloaded html page not opening in chrome or edge but in IE and giving noscript error - vue application

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In my application, i am trying to download html of current page which is with same domain name. I have written some method to download the html and it is downloading.

But, i have tried to open it in chrome as well as edge and it is not opening. But, in IE it is opening and displaying text of noscript tag (**We're sorry but app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled.Please enable it to continue.**).

I am inputting intranet site URL and clicking the download button. Here is my method below.

```
downloadHtml() {
  let url = this.urlInput;  // input text v-model value
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((html) => this.downloadAsFile("report.html", html)); // by this name it is downloading
},
downloadAsFile(name, text) {
  const link = this.createDownloadableLink(name, text);
  const clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click");
  link.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
},
createDownloadableLink(fileName, content) {
  let link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.download = fileName;
  return link;
},
```

****The problems are :**

```
    1. The app root signifies the public/index.html and that downloaded html is this one not the current page's html.

    2. Chrome or Edge is not opening that html page even i checked browser is javascript enabled.
```

So, what i have to change the download the current page html?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an HTML file in not an `application/octet-stream` file type. The mime type of an HTML page is `text/html`

I'm unsure of the way you try to create your download link. I don't have time to test it, but there is the way I do it usually using the `createObjectURL` API :

```js
async function fetchHTML(url) {

let content = await fetch(url).then(resp => resp.text());

let file = new Blob([content],{type:'text/html'});
let href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
let a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = href;
a.setAttribute('download', 'report.html');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));

}
```

Another problem is that you don't append your link into the DOM in the code you provided. So the DOM cannot trigger your mouse event and so starting the download (it's needed by some browsers).

With the good mime type, the file in a proper format and a link in to the dom, it should be ok.

Comment: I have changed the code a bit now. Can you give some more clarity or example of your code?  If there are 3 pages -  http://example.com/about, http://example.com/home, http://example.com/details.   Can i work on that fetch on url change?

Comment: It is not giving html output.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean or what you want to do. The code I provided assume that the result of your fetch request is a valid html file as a string. Then, you want your user to be able to download such html string as an html file and the code I provided works for this purpose. Just try it in your dev tools console replacing content  = fetch by content = '<html><head></head><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>' : it will download an html file readable by any browser. Until you want to do something else, I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: I am passing url as a string in fetch request. That url is like http://example.com/about. Then how can i modify that html file as a string response....

Comment: Your code is working but i am getting [object Response] in report.html file

Comment: It's a strange behavior, with your given code for the fetch call it should work. What did you get if you do this : ` fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then(html => console.log(html));` ?

Comment: Thinking a little bit further I think that you maybe confused with my async/await syntax if you copied my code. I wrapped it into an async function just in case, let me know if it solved your problem and If you need more explanations.

Comment: that fetched HTML itself is showing default index.html which is having noscript tag (We're sorry but app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled.Please enable it to continue.). Do you have any idea how to fetch html from url of same domain.

Comment: Ah. I just got it. You use vue.js to generate your web pages. So, if you try to fetch HTML this way, your server respond with a page that contains that message until JS script change that page to build the view client side. AS it's the browser that render the view, it's content is not available whith a simple fetch request. You must use some tool to be able to do what you want, like nuxt.js, for server-side rendering.

Comment: Yes you are right. Is there any reference you have or any example??

Comment: You may want to watch https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/server-side-rendering 
Another solution can be to use pupeteer that offer a node.js simple api to manage a headless browser. It may be simpler/quicker depending of your needs. You can find more infos at https://pptr.dev/